# How to login as another user and then log out in bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to write a bash script to do something as another user and then return to the initial user...

Suppose I run the following as root:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=zaraza
su - "${USER}"
#do some stuff as zaraza
________ #here I should logout zaraza
#continue doing things as root
```

In the console I should write "exit", but in bash is a keyword and it exits the script...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `su -c`. From the man page:

> ```
>  su man -c catman
>         Runs the command catman as user man.  You will be asked for man's
>         password unless your real UID is 0.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to make the stuff that has to run as the other user a separate script and invoke it with the "-c" option in su, like `su -c otherscript userid`.

You may be able to do that as a "here script" with `<< EOF`, but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

su - ${username} -c /path/to/the/shellscript.sh