# As a root user can I execute commands in BASH as another user without requiring a password?

Tags: linux, bash, root, sudo, rhel

I have a root user account on an RHeL server. On that server I have a simple script called `user.sh` that just returns the current user:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $USER
```

when run from my root account the output is

```
bash user.sh
>>>root
```

From another script I would like to be able to temporarily switch between users without entering a password, [storing the password in the script or a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882310/how-to-switch-to-root-user-without-entering-password-in-bash-script-on-redhat), or [modifying /etc/sudoers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668512/how-to-switch-to-different-user-inside-a-shell-script-and-execute-some-command-w) and execute `user.sh` and then return back to my initial root account. Is this at all possible?

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. [Using delimeters to execute a block of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758235/how-to-execute-a-group-of-commands-as-another-user-in-bash)

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash

   bash /user.sh

   su other_user <<EOF
   echo Current user: $USER
   EOF
   ```

   output:

   ```sh
   root
   Current user: root
   ```
2. switching to a user in bash, executing a command and then logging back out

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash

   bash /user.sh

   su other_user
   bash /user.sh
   exit
   ```

   output: The script pauses execution and returns me to the terminal logged in as `other_user` however I will still be in my root account's directory that contains `user.sh`

   ```sh
   root
   [other_user@my_server]$
   ```

   if I then type `exit` I'm returned to my root account and the script completes execution
3. [using the `su - <username> -c /path/to/the/shellscript.sh` to execute a script as a different account and then return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538624/how-to-login-as-another-user-and-then-log-out-in-bash-script)

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash

   bash /user.sh

   su - other_user -c /path/user.sh
   ```

   output:

   ```sh
   root
   -bash: /path/user.sh: Permission denied
   ```
4. using `sudo -i -u other_user` to log in as the user and execute the script which yields the same problem experienced with attempt #2 but I am redirected to `other_user`'s home directory.

It may be worth noting that if I use method 2, while I'm logged in as `other_user` I am able to run `bash user.sh` and yield the desired output: `other_user`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example, the `$USER` variable is expanded before `su` is executed. This can be prevented by quoting `EOF`.

```
su other_user <<'EOF'
echo Current user: $USER
EOF
```

Or you can execute the script to do it in the root shell, also using a here-doc:

```
su other_user <<END
bash user.sh
END
```

or you can use the `-c` option to `su`:

```
su other_user -c 'bash user.sh'
```

Comment: Right. To clarify, the `echo` command is successfully being run as `other_user`; you've just told it to print `root` because the expansion of `$USER` happened before the `su`.

Comment: Both solutions work! Is there any benefit of one solution over the other, or is it just a matter of using the first answer if you have multiple commands to execute? 

as a side note for anyone else that might need help with the same problem, the above code will yield ```Permission Denied``` if you specify the path to ```user.sh``` instead of just leaving it as it.

Comment: Use whichever seems most convenient for a particular use case.

Comment: It will only yield permission denied if any of the directories in the path are unreadable by `other_user`.